# How to restore backup with rsync

Tags: backup, rsync

I made a backup of my home folder with this command:

```
rsync -avxP /home_folder_path /backup_folder_path
```

How exactly do I restore the backup? Would this command work?

```
rsync -avxP /backup_folder_path /home_folder_path
```

Do I need to include some other flags? Just asking, because last time I tried to restore a backup using another method and something went wrong.

Comment: It's super difficult to understand what your steps were. Can you add proper formatting and write down the paths to make it clearer?

Comment: yes it will work, but in order to know wich options to use (because it depends on your requirements ) you can check `man rsync` pages , OPTIONS SUMMARY section